# Debugging a NSObjectInaccessibleException error. Object's managedobjectcontext becomes nil?

Tags: iphone, debugging, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, fault

I have a simple iphone application in with a one to many gift to recipient relationship (that is, one recipient can get many gifts, but each gift must go to one recipient.  To create a relationship between a gift and a recipient, I am creating first creating a new recipient object in the managed object context, setting a new controller's recipient object to be the new recipient, and then popping the new controller onto the navigationController.  When the new controller returns, I assign the new recipient to the gift.

The code for that transaction:

```
RecipientEditController *nextController = [
                                            [RecipientEditController alloc]
                                            initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped
                                          ];

Recipient *new = [NSEntityDescription 
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipient" 
                  inManagedObjectContext:gift.managedObjectContext
                 ];
[new addGiftsObject:gift];

nextController.recipient = new;
nextController.recipient.hideRelationships = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

if ([new hasData]) {
    gift.recipient = new;
} else {
    [gift.managedObjectContext deleteObject:new];
}

break;
```

Within the new controller, the recipient object seems to operate normally; I can print a description of the recipient within the ViewWillAppear method.  But when I get to the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method, my recipient object is no longer valid: Its managedObjectContextProperty is nil, and a call to recipient.firstName (a property defined in the model class and in the database), an error is thrown.

Error:

```
2011-11-30 17:22:18.111 Gift Hero[36359:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x59e65c0 <x-coredata://97FDB78C-6F65-4B54-8DBB-00A9C6A4B4C8/Recipient/p21>''
```

Any idea what's going on?  This is literally driving me nuts!  How can the recipient just invalidate between displaying the view and showing the table?!

Thanks in advance, PT

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've figured this out.  Pushing a new viewController does **NOT** seem to end execution of the current method, like calling another function might.  So when I delete the object after pushing the view controller, it is deleting the object in the other view controller.  I don't really understand the logic behind this, but it is what it is...